# Unit Tests fail after upgrade to .NET 6.0

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, xunit

We recently upgraded from .NET Framework 4.6 to .NET (6.0).
When try to run unit tests in Test-Explorer, it starts to build and then stops without further notice. In the output-window under "test" i see lots of errors (one for every test-project):

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException:
> Could not find testhost
>
> > at
> > Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Hosting.DotnetTestHostManager.GetTestHostProcessStartInfo(IEnumerable`1 sources, IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, TestRunnerConnectionInfo
> > connectionInfo)
> >
> > > at
> > > Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyOperationManager.SetupChannel(IEnumerable`1
> > > sources, String runSettings)
> > >
> > > > at
> > > > Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyDiscoveryManager.DiscoverTests(DiscoveryCriteria
> > > > discoveryCriteria, ITestDiscoveryEventsHandler2 eventHandler)

More informations: Visual studio 2019, upgrade-assistant changed the previous test suite to xunit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some NuGet-packages were missing. I needed in the end:

- Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk
- xunit
- xunit.runner.visualstudio

[image]

Comment: I was missing `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`. Adding it fixed my issue. Thank you for the help.